# Laravel printing collection outside foreach loop on last element returns Undefined variable

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, collections

I'm having a collection which if is printed inside foreach loop returns whole collection till the end:

```
@foreach($questions as $q)



@endforeach

<a href="{{url('basic-test/'. $q->id) }}" class="btn btn-info">Next</a> //undefined variable on the last item
```

However if I take it outside the for loop right before retrieving last record, I get undefined variable error. My controller:

```
public function getQuestion(Request$request, $id)
{

$first = Question::findOrFail($id);
$request->session()->push('question', $id);
$questions = Question::whereNotIn('id', session('question'))->inRandomOrder()->get();

return view('basicTest') ->with(compact( 'questions', 'first'));
}
```

Comment: what do you mean "if I take it outside the for loop" ... you run the foreach loop then you move that statement outside the loop? not quite clear what you are doing, provide the exact code

Comment: @lagbox updated the question.Yes, run the foreach loop, and take statement outside of it.

Comment: who says the loop is even running? there could be nothing to iterate over, which means `$q` would never be defined and this is why you don't use variables like that outside the loop they are created in ... you keep pushing question ids into that session variable, maybe you are the point you are excluding all questions

Comment: @lagbox I agree it doesn't make sense and it's not a good idea, but it works until the last element, my point is to understand why it works the way it does.

Comment: i dont know what you mean that it works until the last element

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/collections#method-last) `collection` helper to get `last` collection item.

```php
@foreach($questions as $q)

<a href="{{url('basic-test/'. $q->id) }}" class="btn btn-info">Next</a>

@endforeach

<a href="{{url('basic-test/'. $questions->last()->id) }}" class="btn btn-info">Next</a>
```

Your query has an error remove `find()` and change it to, because calling `find()` will return 1 item not collection:

```php
$questions = Question::whereNotIn('id', session('question'))->inRandomOrder()->get();
```

Also because you don't run any `where` on `firstOrFail` you can short it to:

```php
$first = Question::findOrFail($id);
```

Comment: It throws Call to a member function last() on int exception, but I don't see how this would've solved the problem if it returns only the last item?

Comment: Modified your answer to <a href="{{url('basic-test/'. $questions->last()->id) }}" class="btn btn-info">Next</a> but then on the last item Trying to get property 'id' of non-object

Comment: @Jenga Yes sorry should be on `$questions`

Comment: Thanks for noticing other stuff, but the whole point is not to have statement inside foreach, having it inside the loop works either way.

Comment: @Jenga Then not clear what you want to achive, the problem was that you call `find()`, find doesn't return collection this is why you can't run loop / or call last().